# How to create a Docker container for Snakemake

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, snakemake

This is my first attempt at creating a Docker container.
I need to make a container for a legacy version of `VarScan2` so I based much of it off a [`Dockerfile` found for a newer version of `VarScan2`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jeltje/varscan2/dockerfile)

I got an error trying to run the first container I built hinting that it may not be running because `Snakemake.utils` was not available. Therefore I think I need to install `Snakemake` in my container for which I need >= `Python3.5`.

I'm having trouble trying to get `Python3.8` as `Snakemake` is failing to install on `docker build`:

### Error:

```
Downloading snakemake-5.26.1.tar.gz (237 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_50ix5/snakemake/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_50ix5/snakemake/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-AMGZ1t
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_50ix5/snakemake/
    Complete output (2 lines):
    At least Python 3.5 is required.
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Matthew Jordan Oldach, moldach686@gmail.com

# create a working directory and work from there
RUN mkdir /tmp/install
WORKDIR /tmp/install

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        libncurses5-dev \
        libgdbm-dev \
        libnss3-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        gcc \
        make \
        zlib1g-dev \
        git \
        wget \
        python3-pip \
        default-jre \
        r-base \
        bc

# [Download Python3.7.5 following these instructions][2]
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.7.5.tgz
RUN tar -xf Python-3.7.5.tgz
RUN cd python-3.7.5; ./configure --enable-optimizations; cd ..

# Download Snakemake
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python get-pip.py
RUN pip install snakemake

# Samtools 0.1.18 - note: 0.1.19 and 1.1 do NOT work, VarScan copynumber dies on the mpileup
RUN wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/samtools/samtools/0.1.18/samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2
RUN tar -xvf samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2
# the make command generates a lot of warnings, none of them relevant to the final samtools code, hence 2>/dev/null
#RUN (cd samtools-0.1.18/ && make DFLAGS='-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_USE_KNETFILE -D_CURSES_LIB=0' LIBCURSES='' 2>/dev/null && mv samtools /usr/local/bin)

# get varscan 
RUN wget  -O /usr/local/bin/VarScan.jar https://netactuate.dl.sourceforge.net/project/varscan/VarScan.v2.3.9.jar
# Set WORKDIR to /data -- predefined mount location.
RUN mkdir /data
WORKDIR /data

# And clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/install

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "java -jar /usr/local/bin/VarScan.jar"]
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me figure out what's going wrong here, thanks.

#### Update

The solution by [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) solved this solution.

Dockerfile Solution

```
FROM python:3.7.5

MAINTAINER Matthew Jordan Oldach, moldach686@gmail.com

# create a working directory and work from there
RUN mkdir /tmp/install
WORKDIR /tmp/install

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        gcc \
        make \
        zlib1g-dev \
        git \
        wget \
        python3-pip \
        default-jre \
        r-base \
        bc

# Download Snakemake
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python get-pip.py
RUN pip install snakemake

# Samtools 0.1.18 - note: 0.1.19 and 1.1 do NOT work, VarScan copynumber dies on the mpileup
RUN wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/samtools/samtools/0.1.18/samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2
RUN tar -xvf samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2
# the make command generates a lot of warnings, none of them relevant to the final samtools code, hence 2>/dev/null
#RUN (cd samtools-0.1.18/ && make DFLAGS='-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_USE_KNETFILE -D_CURSES_LIB=0' LIBCURSES='' 2>/dev/null && mv samtools /usr/local/bin)

# get varscan 
RUN wget  -O /usr/local/bin/VarScan.jar https://netactuate.dl.sourceforge.net/project/varscan/VarScan.v2.3.9.jar
# Set WORKDIR to /data -- predefined mount location.
RUN mkdir /data
WORKDIR /data

# And clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/install

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "java -jar /usr/local/bin/VarScan.jar"]
```

Comment: Why not start `FROM python:3.7`? Otherwise, you need to update the PATH to use Python3 by default, or `RUN python3.7 -m pip intall snakemake`

Comment: Thanks [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) that worked!

Comment: Cool. You can post your solution below rather than update the question

Comment: Looking back over this it looks a bit redundant. Does `snakemake` come in the `wheel` of `FROM python:3.7.5` and maybe I don't need the `RUN` call(s) to install snakemake as well? Also, it looks like I included pip twice (or two versions?)

Comment: 1) No existing packages would be there 2) pip comes with Python 3.4+

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll post the final solution below. One more thing, so I can get rid of `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and replace my three `RUN` lines for the "Download Snakemake" with your `RUN python3.7 -m pip install  snakemake` instead correct?

Comment: Havent personally tried, but seems right